# Scrapyrt error after install scrapyrt is not recognized as a command

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and trying to use scrapyrt to follow a udemy course. Why am I getting the following error when trying to start scrapyrt as it says in the docs.

```
scrapyrt : The term 'scrapyrt' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ scrapyrt
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (scrapyrt:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I installed scrapyrt the way it says to in the docs but when I try to run it in my terminal I get this error. I looking for it to start an endpoint for my scrapy spider.

```
scrapyrt : The term 'scrapyrt' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ scrapyrt
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (scrapyrt:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Dont see how its confusing but ok

Comment: try running it from a clean virtual enviornment